# It is possible to refresh/reload a jqgrid in another view/page after a button is click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

Hello I am new to this site. For my title above it possible to reload the data of a jqgrid in a different `view/page` after I click my button?. I know how to reload a jqgrid but it it is on the same view the button and my jqgrid. I am thinking this scenario

**SCENARIO**

Page 2 is already open for the reloading of data in jqgrid. After I click the button from Page 1 the jqgrid in Page 2 will reload. The event is `saving of data` or do I really need to refresh my Page 2 `(Press F5)` to view the saved data?.

BTW I am using a `jqgrid 4.3.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I am not sure what server side language you are using but using web-sockets or signalR you can send a message to all open pages to refresh if data has been refreshed on server. You can also use polling to achieve that.
Concept is this:

- You update data from grid or anywhere on page 1 and that goes to server. Now you want to refresh pages that may contain this data or intend to show it.
- Polling : On all such pages you refresh the data from server if there is a change obtained from polling
- SignalR : You can use a hub to send a method to all clients to run a javascript code that checks for grid presence and then refresh it.

There are other methods as well where when someone hits a page that has grid you can make an entry in database about that page and save its sate as valid. When you update something that makes this data invalid then you can poll all pages in this table and tell user to/or automatically refresh the grid for all such pages.

I have only done this in signalR which wraps polling and websockets so you can use any of these if signalR is not your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I search about signalR and found some link of tutorial on how to do it. But as a new web programmer like me it is hard to start to embed the code into my project

Comment: Dont worry. Forget about finding code that work for you. its easy to write code that you can debug and learn how it works and it will. Start and ask where you get stuck. Best is to create an open source small project on git and community will help you in learning and coding.

Comment: Ok i will. I try to test it into my project. If i got stuck and i dunno how to fix i will comment again here.